# Get Value of Appended Element After Submit Button with POST Type Form

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, post

I want to get the value of appended elements after submitting. It appends the right name attributes, but I can't get the value

```
<script>
    <?php
        $options = '';
        while($searched_species_adding = mysqli_fetch_array($search_species_adding)){
            $name = $searched_species_adding['name'];
            $options = $options.'<option>'.$name.'</option>';
        }
        echo 'var options = "'.$options.'";';
    ?>
    var count=2;
    $( "#add-species" ).click(function() {
      var html=$("<tr id='species-"+count+"'><td><select name='species-"+count+"' class='form-control'>"+options+"</select></td><td><input id='species-num-"+count+"' name='species-num-"+count+"' class='form-control' type='number'></td></tr>");
        $("#species-container").append(html);
        $("#species-num-"+count).prop('required',true);
        count++;
        var wew = ($('tr', $("#wew").find('tbody')).length);
        $(".tr-num").remove();
        $("#species-container").append("<input class='tr-num' type='hidden' value='"+wew+"' name='tr_count'>");
        $(".tr-num").val(wew);
    });

    $( "#remove-species" ).click(function() {
        count--;
        $("#species-"+count).remove();
        var wew = ($('tr', $("#wew").find('tbody')).length);
        $(".tr-num").val(wew);
    });
</script>
```

Above is the script for appending.
And here is my code in getting the values in a form after submitting:

```
if(isset($_POST['add-delivered'])){

$requestor = $_POST['requestor'];
$org_office = $_POST['org_office'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$date_pickup = $_POST['date_pickup'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$planting_type = $_POST['planting_type'];
$tr_count = $_POST['tr_count'];
$species = '';
for($x = 1; $x <= $tr_count; $x++){
    $species = $species.$_POST['species-'.$x];
}

echo '<script>alert("'.$tr_count.'")</script>';

exit();
```

}

Comment: Please try to reduce your code to the absolute smallest that still causes the problem. That will make it much easier to help you, and you will also increase the likelihood of finding the problem yourself.

Comment: If you are using default form submit process....it will load a new page. All script from previous page is gone and new script is loaded

Comment: I just found the right answer by just understanding how it really works. Thanks by the way. :)